# Does God want humans to achieve real union with Him?

Tags: moksha

I believe in God, but I'm not sure God wants humans to achieve a real union with Him.

After all, infinity in space, time and as an intellectual concept is a seemingly unsurpassable limit for humans.

We could remain always separate from God but continually improve in adoring Him and delight in the marvels of His creation while helping each other do the same.

Is there a school of Hinduism that endorses this view?